# Unable to connect to tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7, war, web-deployment

I deployed a new version of a .war file and the tomcat7 is also running fine as status shows me:

```
root@s17298254:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps# service tomcat7 status
 * Tomcat servlet engine is running with pid 11331
```

Now the question is that neither I am able to view the website, nor I am able to view the manager interface in my web browser. Please note that its in production environment that I am using this tomcat instance. What could be the reason?

I have tried many things like running tomcat as root user previlages(although a disaster recepie, but atleast to make things work temporarily), putting

```
useIPVHosts="true"
```

under `<Connector>` etc.
Here is my catalina.out:

```
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlValidation' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlNamespaceAware' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/Logger'.
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2038 ms
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/camriders/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Mar 12, 2014 7:04:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

It does not show me anything pathogenic.So what could be the cause that my website is now no longer working?

**EDIT:**

The error when i type in browser mywebsite.mydomain.net is:

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at mywebsite.mydomain.net.
Similar with google chrome.

Comment: Appears spring is frozen in its initialisation

Comment: @hd1 so whats the solution? Is it an error related to tomcat or something wrong with the .war file.Seems some tomcat issue as i am not able to view the tomcat manager interface in browser.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: If I had a solution, I'd have posted an answer.

Comment: @UVM Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at mywebsite.mydomain.net.

Comment: Please go through this link http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/IP-based-virtual-hosting-with-useIPVHosts-true-always-goes-to-default-host-td4982160.html.  You need some patience.

Comment: Take 3 thread dumps approx. 10s apart and use those to figure out where and why the web application start has hung.

Comment: @MarkThomas see this line: INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/camriders/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class Could this cause problems?

Comment: No. That is an INFO message, not an ERROR message. It is something you need to fix but not something that should cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat 7 use 'xmlValidation' and 'xmlNamespaceAware' under context element.

```
<Context path="" docBase="ROOT" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false"/>
```